# Dividing a list into more, smaller, lists

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the list `{3,5,4,2}`, is there a way to divide this list into smaller lists of the form `{3},{5},{4},{2}`?

Comment: `Transpose[{lst}] == Thread[List[lst]] ==  List /@ lst == {{3}, {5}, {4}, {2}}`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @TomD Or indeed `Partition[lst, 1]`

Comment: @ Feyre. `Partition[lst, 1]` is good to know. Just for fun: `Tuples[lst, {1}] == Flatten[{lst}, {{2}}] == MapThread[List, {lst}] ==Subsets[lst, {1}] == {{3}, {5}, {4}, {2}}`

Comment: @TomD Actually, you did know about `Partition[lst,1]`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8862046/499167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example

**Code**

```
List /@ {3,5,4,2}
```

**Output**

> {{3}, {5}, {4}, {2}}

**Reference**

[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

Comment: 'List/@{3,5,4,2}' is shorter.(+1)

Comment: @kglr ;D you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Since your Data are already a [List](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) you can use [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to access Values:

```
{3, 5, 4, 2}[[1]]
```

> 3

```
myList = {3, 5, 4, 2};

myList[[1]]*myList[[3]]
```

> 12

Nota Bene, everything in the comments seem right, however, you can also work with [Subsets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subset.html):

```
lst = {3, 5, 4, 2};

s1 = Subsets[lst, {1}]
```

> {{3}, {5}, {4}, {2}}

```
m = s1[[1]]
```

> {3}

```
n = s1[[3]]
```

> {4}

```
m*n
```

> {12}